# Is it possible to execute some infinite loop function automatically using Vue after the web completing loading?

Tags: vue.js

I know life hooks in Vue,but I want to execute a infinite loop function automatically after the page finish loading. How can I use Vue to achieve that? I have put the function in mounted(), but it cause a error.

Comment: Which error? Maximum call stack size exceeded?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: Do you use the `setInterval` for the infinite loop, or just some thing like `for (true) { ... } ` ?

Comment: thank you. I have fixed it. It's a setInterval problem